# Reshape 1-D Numpy Array to 2-D

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, reshape

I have a 1-D numpy array of 38 (x,y) coordinates created by (doc [here](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018w00000015000000)):

```
npArray = arcpy.da.FeatureClassToNumPyArray(fc,["SHAPE@XY"])
```

This outputs a (38,) array, like:

```
[([X1, Y1],)
 ([X2, Y2],)
 ...
 ([X38, Y38],)]
```

edit: Here are the first 5 lines of actual output, and the dtype:

```
[([614276.776070848, 6086493.437772478],)
 ([626803.3576861953, 6101090.488548568],)
 ([627337.6049131282, 6100051.791447324],)
 ([627340.8526022129, 6099601.263191574],)
 ([629011.3422856168, 6099079.306533674],)

dtype([('SHAPE@XY', '<f8', (2,))])
```

but I want a (38,2) array like:

```
[(X1, Y1)
 (X2, Y2)
 ...
 (X38, Y38)]
```

How do I make this happen?

I've tried

```
numpy.reshape(npArray, (-1,2))
```

but this reshuffles the coordinate pairs to a (19,2) array.

Comment: Your example vectors are confusing (the commas/parentheses don't make any sense to me). Could you paste the actual output of `print(npArray)` ?

Comment: This looks like a structured array.  What is the `dtype`?

Comment: @agomcas it's legal. the parens show in each tuple, there is one array as only element, which contains x,y coordinate. strange though.

Comment: @hpaulj ive edited to include dtype: dtype([('SHAPE@XY', '<f8', (2,))])

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr quite strange indeed. If I try to create an array like that I cannot get past the first element, due to missing commas between the tuples. (The interpreter then assumes I am trying to _call_ tuple1(tuple2) ) So I guess it is some kind of weird printing output...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The doc http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018w00000015000000  says it returns a structured array.

Since the `dtype` is:

```
dtype([('SHAPE@XY', '<f8', (2,))
```

you can access this `field` by name

```
npArray['SHAPE@XY']
```

the result should be a `(38,2)` array.  It will be a `view` on the original.

---

Creating a structured array like this from scratch is a bit tricky, since `numpy` tries to create the highest dimensional array it can.  The surest way is to create an empty array of the desired size and dtype, and then assign values field by field.

```
In [56]: X=np.zeros((5,),dtype=([('f0',int,(2,))]))
In [57]: X
Out[57]: 
array([([0, 0],), ([0, 0],), ([0, 0],), ([0, 0],), ([0, 0],)], 
      dtype=[('f0', '<i4', (2,))])
In [58]: X['f0']=np.arange(10).reshape(5,2)
In [59]: X
Out[59]: 
array([([0, 1],), ([2, 3],), ([4, 5],), ([6, 7],), ([8, 9],)], 
      dtype=[('f0', '<i4', (2,))])
In [60]: X['f0']
Out[60]: 
array([[0, 1],
       [2, 3],
       [4, 5],
       [6, 7],
       [8, 9]])
```

Comment: Thank you for the thorough explanation! I did start with the doc, but obviously using npArray['SHAPE@XY'] rather than npArray itself wasn't clear to me.

Answer (score 1):

Does numpy.squeeze(numpy.array(npArray)) work? If not, can you post an array with numbers?

EDIT: I've not used arcpy (may be worth tagging this in the question) but from the docs here: 
http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018w00000015000000

It looks like you need to use npArray["SHAPE@XY"] to access the numpy array. The array should then already be the required shape.

Comment: No, numpy.squeeze does not affect the original array.